# Create form doesn't work sapui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a master-detail application that consumes an OData service.

I also have a create form in fragment named "DetailCreateMode.fragment.xml" that's supposed to create notifications. Unfortunatly, it does not create them.

Here's my fragment :

```
 <core:FragmentDefinition height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"     xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form">
<Panel>
<content>
<f:SimpleForm id="iconTabFilter1form" minWidth="1024" editable="false" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3"
            emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" columnsL="1">
            <f:content>
                <Label text="Equipement" required="false"/>
                <Input name="Equnr" id="Equnr_id" valueLiveUpdate="true" liveChange="_validateSaveEnablement"
                enabled="false" visible="true"
                value="{ path: 'Eqktx', type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.String' , constraints:{ maxLength:18, nullable:false } }"/>

                <Label text="Désignation" required="true"/>
                <Input name="Qmtxt" id="Qmtxt_id"     valueLiveUpdate="true" liveChange="_validateSaveEnablement"
                enabled="true" visible="true"
                value="{ path: 'Qmtxt', type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.String' , constraints:{ maxLength:40, nullable:false } }"/>

                <Label text="Date Avis" required="true"/>
                <DatePicker id="Qmdat" displayFormat="short" change="_validateSaveEnablement"
                 value="{ path: 'Qmdat', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style : 'long' }  }"/>    

            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
    </content>
</Panel>
```

Here's the button that saves and creates :

```
<Button id="saveButton" press="saveChanges" icon="sap-icon://save"></Button>
```

And last but not least, here's the function in detail controller :

```
saveChanges: function() {
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    var mNewEntry = {};

    mNewEntry.Equnr = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Equnr_id");
    mNewEntry.Qmtxt = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Qmtxt_id");
    mNewEntry.Qmdat = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Date Avis");
    oModel.create("/avisSet", mNewEntry, null, function(oData){
        MessageBox.show(
            "Created succesfully",{
            icon : sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.SUCCESS,
            title : "Dear User",
            styleClass : "sapUiSizeCompact"
            }
            );
    }, function(err){
        MessageBox.show(
            "ERROR",{
            icon : sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.ERROR,
            title : "Dear User",
            styleClass : "sapUiSizeCompact"
            }
            );
    }
    );
      oModel.refresh();  
    },
```

If i take a guess, i'd say that the values mNewEntry.Equnr, ... are undefined

Answer (score 0):

Please, change this:

```
 mNewEntry.Equnr = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Equnr_id");
 mNewEntry.Qmtxt = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Qmtxt_id");
 mNewEntry.Qmdat = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Date Avis");
```

to this:

```
 mNewEntry.Equnr = this.byId("Equnr_id");
 mNewEntry.Qmtxt = this.byId("Qmtxt_id");
 mNewEntry.Qmdat = this.byId("Date Avis");
```

EDITED 17:10 140317:

Example:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleForm480_Trial/preview

Comment: thank you for your response Jaro.
Unfortunatly it still recognizes the variables ( mNewEntry.Equnr, mNewEntry.Qmtxt, mNewEntry.Qmdat) as undefined.

Comment: Anas, you must past instance of used fragment to the function saveChanges, otherwise it will be undefined. If it will be passed correctly, you will be able to find it by this.byId("Equnr_id") etc.

Comment: I'll be grateful if you could you give me an example.

Comment: Maybe this inspires you https://jsbin.com/saqejaqine/2/edit?html,js,output and please what do you get in the SaveChanges when you use var a = this.getParent(). What is in a?

Comment: Anas and please also try mNewEntry.Equnr = this.getView().byId("Enqur_id");

Comment: Jaro, i changed sap.ui.getCore().byId("Equnr_id") to this.getView().byId("Enqur_id") and still nothing !!

Comment: Ok Anas, can you make jsbin example of your code and I will have a look. Also have a look at the example I put in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the value of the input like so:

```
mNewEntry.Equnr = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Equnr_id").getValue();
mNewEntry.Qmtxt = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Qmtxt_id").getValue();
mNewEntry.Qmdat = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Date Avis").getValue();
```